# Multiple List Deletion

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a set of lists that I want to mass delete but I would normally have to attach the object first is their a cleaner way of doing this. I dontfind it pretty having to do this for each object I am sure there would be a neater way of doing this ?.

```
public void DeleteCustomer(int CustomerId)
    {
        using (var myContext = new customerDbEntities())
        {
            Customer DeleteCustomer = myContext.Customers.Where(c => c.id == CustomerId).SingleOrDefault();
            myContext.Customers.Remove(DeleteCustomer);


            List<ContractDetail> DeleteContracts = myContext.ContractDetails.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.ContractDetails.RemoveRange(DeleteContracts);


            List <Note> DeleteNotes = myContext.Notes.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.Notes.RemoveRange(DeleteNotes);


            List <ProgamType> ProgTypes = myContext.ProgamTypes.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.ProgamTypes.RemoveRange(ProgTypes);


            List<AddOn> AddonsList = myContext.AddOns.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.AddOns.RemoveRange(AddonsList);

            List<revenue> revenueList = myContext.revenues.Where(c => c.customerid == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.revenues.RemoveRange(revenueList);

            List<Implentat> ImplentatList = myContext.Implentats.Where(c => c.customerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.Implentats.RemoveRange(ImplentatList);


            List<CustomerContact> CustomerContactsList = myContext.CustomerContacts.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.CustomerContacts.RemoveRange(CustomerContactsList);


            List<CustomField> CustomFields = myContext.CustomFields.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.CustomFields.RemoveRange(CustomFields);

        }
    }
```

Cause when I use Attach is does not allow the list as it of type entity, what should i be passing instead and how would i make this a more common routine.

```
     List <Note> DeleteNotes = myContext.Notes.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
            myContext.Notes.Attach(DeleteNotes);  // Does not like here
            myContext.Notes.RemoveRange(DeleteNotes);
```

Comment: It looks like you want to setup your foreign keys with cascade delete https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: did you try parent table last and attached table first?

Comment: @juharr i dont want to do that as it would effect how I have to add items in entity framework

Comment: The cascade delete doesn't effect the order you have to add, only non null foreign keys effect that.  You'd only avoid cascade if instead of deleting related rows you wanted to null out the foreign key instead.